# Untouchable ListView within tabhost

Tags: android, listview

I've been agonising for a while now about something which ought to be relatively simple, but I can't seem to get it to work. The data for each ListView is displaying correctly, and I can select and activate the onItemClickListener by using the trackball. However, I cannot scroll down or select any of the items by touch, which I know I should be able to. Any help much appreciated. My code and xml follows:

```
public class POITab extends TabActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.poitab);

    ListView raillist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.raillist);
    Cursor mrailStationsCursor = db.type_query(KEY_RAIL);
    setupTab(raillist, mrailStationsCursor, "Rail", R.drawable.logo);

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Log.i("touched", " yes");
}

public void setupTab (ListView list, Cursor cursor, String tabname, int drawable) {
startManagingCursor(cursor);
String[] from_all = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_NAME};
int[] to_all = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
list.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from_all, to_all));
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

TabHost.TabSpec spec= getTabHost().newTabSpec(tabname);
spec.setContent(list.getId());
spec.setIndicator(tabname, getResources().getDrawable(drawable));
getTabHost().addTab(spec);
}
 }
```

poitab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="62px">
<ListView android:id="@+id/raillist"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
</FrameLayout>
</TabHost>`
```

Comment: to give some further ideas, I've found that I can scroll and select using touch, but only right at the bottom of the screen in the emulator and the phone. Could it be that the Frame Layout is somehow overriding the ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what the problem was - I had a ListView declared in the layout (not shown above, perhaps I should have included the whole source) that wasn't being used, and all touch events were being handled by that. So, moral of the story, only have the ListViews that you need within a TabHost, otherwise it will cause you problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same problem, but I don't have another ListView in my layout...